# Repack inference model with requirements.txt inside source_dir without installing them during the process in SageMaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

After training a custom model, i need to create an inference model and then deploy the relevant endpoint.

When, in the execution of the pipeline, i have to inject a custom inference script, a model repacking process is triggered. The inference model needs to have the `requirements.txt` file (the same as the trained model).

When the repacking process is started, a default machine `ml.m5.large` with the training image `sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3` is instantiated. If the `requirements.txt` file is present in the inference code folder, this process will try to install the packages (although it is not necessary, should be a simple repacking of a tar.gz!).

Unfortunately, having specified particular library versions, it will fail.

For example:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.22.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22. 0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.0rc3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.3 Requires-Python >=3. 8; 1.22.4 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23. 0rc3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.4 Requires-Python >=3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.23.0
```

This is the code I'm running:

```py
inf_img_uri = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve(
    framework='pytorch',
    region=region,
    image_scope='inference',
    version="1.12.0",
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    py_version='py38'
)

pytorch_model = Model(
    image_uri=inf_img_uri,
    model_data=step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts,
    role=role,
    entry_point='inference.py',
    sagemaker_session=PipelineSession(),
    source_dir=os.path.join(LIB_DIR, "test"),  # here is inference.py and requirements.txt
    name=model_name,
)

step_create_model = ModelStep(
    name="infTest",
    step_args=pytorch_model.create(instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge"),
    description = 'Create model for inference'
)
```

Is there any way to prevent the template repack from trying to install packages from the `requirements.txt`?

**My current solution**: I have omitted the file in the directory and manually install the packages with `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])` in the inference code. But I find this approach wrong for **Batch Inference** processes (since it would be executed every time) and also inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SageMaker SDK will always repackage the tar ball to include the `inference.py` script and then re-upload the tar ball to S3.

In general, SageMaker Framework containers will install the packages specified in the `requirements.txt` file.

If you do not want this to occur you can leave out the `requirements.txt` file and extend the `sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py` container to include all the necessary dependencies. That way the packages will be baked into the image and every time you kick off a Batch Transform Job the packages will not be installed again.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/prebuilt-containers-extend.html

Comment: But this way, every time I change something in the inference code, do I have to redo the container build/extension before launching the pipeline?

Comment: If you update the inference.py script to make use of packages that are not installed in the container you would have to build and push an update to the container with the new packages added. While you can use a requirements.txt file to install packages you could also just pip install in the inference.py script. But if you wanted to avoid installing packages every time you kick of a Batch Transform Job, your best be would be to bake in the packages into the container.